# How to handle mypy optional property which has already been validated?

Tags: python, mypy

I have the following code:

```
    @property
    def is_idle(self) -> bool:
        return self.current_activity is None

    def tick(self) -> None:
        if self.is_idle:
            return

        self.current_activity.tick()
```

However mypy is not happy about it because it doesn't understand that is_idle already checked if the current_activity was defined or not.

[image: MyPy error message]

Do you know how to tell MyPy that we are sure that the value is defined here?

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, you can insert an assert:

```
assert self.current_activity is not None
```

In general, this is not possible, because MyPy doesn't look inside the other called function. So you will end up repeating `assert`s that you already know are true.